# User controlled SceneKit object orbiting a sphere acts strangely at the poles

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, scenekit, euler-angles

The user controls a snake moving on the surface of a sphere. I have the camera and the head of the snake attached to an imaginary sphere the same size as the visible one:

```
    headNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    controlNode.addChildNode(headNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(controlNode)
```

The user taps two buttons to rotate the snake left and right. I use some basic trig to convert this "2D" rotation into its components which I use to rotate the controlNode every frame:

```
    velocity.x = cos(rotation)
    velocity.y = sin(rotation)

    controlNode.eulerAngles.x += velocity.x
    controlNode.eulerAngles.y += velocity.y
```

This works very smoothly when moving over the majority of the sphere but at the two poles of the sphere (along the y axis) the snake behaves strangely. Here is a gif that shows the normal movement along the majority of the sphere and then the strange movement at the poles:

[the gif was too large to upload so it is on imgur](http://i.imgur.com/LZenpIj.gif)

The way it moves is like it bounces off the poles and I cannot for the life of me work it out. If anyone has a suggestion of an easier way to do the task it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Gimbal Lock was the issue. I fixed it by using the transform component of the node.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!  Can you describe the details of how you calculate the object's transform?  I was going to suggest that you could represent the position and increments to the position with quaternions.  I see that `SCNNode` offers a quaternion `orientation` property, and while SceneKit does not have good quaternion arithmetic functions, GLKit *does* offer them.  So you could potentially work in `GLKQuaternions` and convert back to a 4x4 matrix transform for SceneKit via `SCNMatrix4MakeRotation`, `GLKQuaternionAngle`, and `GLKQuaternionAxis`.

Comment: I wish to work in pure Swift and it does not support many GLK methods so I avoided Quaternions and used simple matrix transformations instead. Creating one rotation around the x axis and another around the y, multiplying them then premultiplying with the current node transform component. Works a charm!